# Are software titles italicized?

Tags: quotes, typography, italics

The titles of freestanding works (books, movies, plays, albums, etc.) are italicized; smaller parts within these works (chapters in a book, articles in a magazine, songs within an album) are not (they are put in quotes, instead).

How are software titles treated?

My understanding is that if a particular program resembles a book or a dramatic work (like a video game), its title is italicized -- otherwise, it is treated as a proper noun, just like any other product.

> I played *Grand Theft Auto*, instead of reading "Democracy in Ancient Greece" in *Microsoft Encarta* and preparing my presentation in PowerPoint.

Is this approach correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on the style guide you're following.

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style/Titles#Italics) says yes for games, and no for other software:

  > Italic type (*text like this*) is generally used for the following categories of titles:
  >
  > ...
  >
  > - Works of art and artifice
  >
  >   Computer and video games (but not other software)
- [*The Guardian*](http://www.guardian.co.uk/styleguide/i) says no:

  > Use roman for titles of books, films, etc
  > ...
  > Use italics for foreign words and phrases (with roman translation in brackets)
- [*National Geographic*](http://stylemanual.ngs.org/home/I/italic) says yes:

  > The following are printed in italic type without quotation marks:
  > ...
  > 2.    Titles of the following:
  > ...
  > Computer software and CD-ROM and other multimedia product titles
  > (except applications programs such as WordPerfect)

Take your pick, and be consistent.